# Ninject: How to bind interface depending on target assembly

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have an interface implemented by two different classes. Then, how can I say to Ninject that I want to bind it to implementation A in some assembly and to implementation B in some other assembly ?

Comment: What do you believe is the relevant factor to prompt you to state that there are multiple assemblies, and how do you perceive that this makes it different to 'normal' use?

Comment: This is known as "conditional binding". Google and you'll have your answers.

Comment: The question is vague. Please show an example. Are you talking about injecting that interface into classes that live in different assemblies?

Comment: I wanted to decide which class inject depending on which is the requesting assembly.Also, you can see the answer selected as solution to fully understand what I meant before. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [contextual binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding):

```
Bind<IFoo>.To<Foo>.When(request =>
    request.Target.Type.Assembly.FullName == "someAssembly");
Bind<IFoo>.To<Bar>.When(request =>
    request.Target.Type.Assembly.FullName == "someOtherAssembly");
```